# static div columns in a div row?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, static, width

Hi I have a web page formatted with 4 div columns in a single div row I'd like to make this
more responsive with bootstrap ...however Id like the column widths to remain static 200px wide and have them just "pop under" as the webpage is re-sized narrower.
is that possible ? I have tried renaming the class=columns to class=col-md-3

then tried wrapping the div pairs in  ... tags bot of these 
attempt were unsatisfactory

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
* {margin: 0; padding: 3px;}
#container {height: 800%; width:900%; font-size: 10px;}
.columns,.spacer{display: inline-block; *display: inline; zoom: 0; vertical-align: top; font-size: 12px;}
.columns {background-color: white; width: 300px; height: 700px;}
.columns {box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;}
.spacer {background-color: transparent; width: 1px; height: 1px;}
.footerDIV {box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;}
.footerDIV {background-color: white; width: 620px; height: 100px;font-size: 12px;}
.spacerHorizontal {background-color: transparent; width: 10px; height: 10px; font-size: 12px;}
A{text-decoration:none}
</style>
<link href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="./bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="./jquery.js"></script>
<script src="./jquery.corner.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div class="row">

 <div class="columns" id="Admissions" style='border-radius: 10px;  background-repeat: no-repeat;'>1</div>
 <div id=1spacer1 class=spacer style="background-color: #white; width: 3px; height: 4px;"></div>

 <div class="columns" id="Headcount"  style='border-radius: 10px;  background-repeat: no-repeat;'>2</div>
 <div id=2spacer1 class=spacer style="background-color: #white; width: 3px; height: 4px;"></div>

 <div class="columns" id="Test1"      style='border-radius: 10px;  background-repeat: no-repeat;'>3</div>
 <div id=3spacer1 class=spacer style="background-color: #white; width: 3px; height: 4px;"></div>

 <div class="columns" id="Test2"      style='border-radius: 10px;  background-repeat: no-repeat;'>4</div>
 <div id=4spacer1 class=spacer style="background-color: #white; width: 3px; height: 4px;"></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

any suggestions how to make this work

Answer (score 2):

add the width="200" within the div brackets. I would imagine that would work?

Comment: Also, you can set a width by a % as well. I personally prefer % over px. :)